# Bootbox don't defined with RequireJS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I am trying to use Bootbox with RequireJS, but every time this error appears:

> ReferenceError: bootbox is not defined

I configured RequireJS with the dependencies:

```
var
bowerLocal = "../../../bower_components/",
asstsLocal = "../../assets/";

requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": bowerLocal + "jquery/dist/jquery.min",
        "jquery.bootbox": bowerLocal + "bootbox/bootbox",
        "jquery.bootstrap": bowerLocal + "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min",
        "jquery.elevateZoom": bowerLocal + "elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-2.2.3.min",
        "jquery.maskedInput": bowerLocal + "jquery-maskedinput/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min"
    },
    /**
     * Define as dependências de bibliotecas.
     */
    shim: {
        "jquery.bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "jquery.elevateZoom": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "jquery.maskedInput": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "jquery.bootbox": {
            deps: ["jquery", "jquery.bootstrap"],
            exports: 'bootbox'
        }
    }
});

require(
    ["jquery", "jquery.bootstrap", "jquery.bootbox", "jquery.maskedInput", "jquery.elevateZoom"],
    function (util) {

bootbox.alert("Hi");
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootbox is not defined on window in AMD mode, you
have to define it yourself, so after doing the below it works now.

```
define(["bootbox"], function(bootbox){
 bootbox.alert("Hello Bootbox");
});
```

Of course the path is defined in `require.config()`, This will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think in @Pushker's answer he typed `define` where he actually wanted to type `require`:

`require(["bootbox"], function(bootbox) {
   bootbox.alert("Hello Bootbox");
});`

(he also mistyped a `}` for a `{`.

Furthermore, when having multiple dependencies you should also specify these as parameter's of the function within your `require` AND make sure they are in the same order as in the string array parameter. E.g. like so:

`require(["jquery", "jquery.bootstrap", "jquery.bootbox", ...],
    function(jquery, bootstrap, bootbox, ...) {
       bootbox.alert("Hi");
    }
...
});`

Check my fiddle for a working Bootbox example: http://jsfiddle.net/bartvanderwal/L1emr4up/